# How to install newest dovecot stable when ubuntu repository is old?

Tags: 12.04, server, dovecot

This is a bit of a dumb question, but how do I install the newest stable of dovecot on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server? I'm still a bit new to ubuntu and linux in general.

The newest stable is v2.2.1, but in the ubuntu repository it's only v2.0.19. The backports repository is only at v2.1.7-2.

I would rather not install from source since it seems like huge trouble when trying to upgrade and handling old dependencies.

I found their stable deb packages [here](http://xi.rename-it.nl/debian/dists/stable-auto/dovecot-2.2/), but how does it relate to the command:

```
apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
```

Does the deb file contain both dovecot-imapd and dovecot-pop3d or whatever else I need to install dovecot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question can be broken down into different questions:

- Installing from the official repositories will provide me the latest version?

No, the version from stable repositories is commonly [not the latest version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software), but a less recent version that has been tested for reliability, security and stability. If one wants the latest version of a package, usually you have to visit the project site or google for the official page and download and compile the source or, if available, the binaries.

- If I install from source, will I get automatic updates?

No.

- If I install the binaries, will I get automatic updates?

It depends. Usually binaries that you decompress and run (like .sh files) will not get updates from apt-get.

Occasionally, some `.deb` files *might* contain information for installing new repositories (dropbox acts this way), and in this case if you install their .deb files you will get automatic updates from ap-get and system updates.

- How do I install manually a new repository?

The link you provided is not a link to the deb files themselves (they are located [here](http://xi.rename-it.nl/debian/pool/stable-auto/dovecot-2.2/)), but to a dovecote repository. You can [follow these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/add-applications/C/adding-repos.html) to add this repo to your repo list, and then [use pining](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) to install the latest version of dovecot.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The latter seems to be the easier way to go in terms of future maintenance.

Comment: If I added `../stable-auto/dovecot-2.2` to my repo list, what happens if dovecot-3.0 comes out? Will I have to manually remove dovecot-2.2 and add the dovecot-3.0 repo to get updates? I'm guessing currently apt-get will pull any updates that are in v2.2.x?

Comment: If it does, it may be a major version change that may break things. In which case *not* automatically updating is best since you will want to test to see if anything is broken before deploying.